# Python script to download directory from URL

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I want to copy my own photos in a given web directory to my Raspberry so I can display them in a slideshow.
I'm looking for a "simple" script to download these files using python. I can then paste this code into my slideshow so that it refreshes the pics every day.

I suppose that the python wget utility would be the tool to use. However, I can only find examples on how to download a single file, not a whole directory.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the server used to host the images and if the script can see a list of images to download. If this list isn't there in some form e.g. a webpage list, JSON or XML feed, there is no way for a script to download the files as the script doesnt "know" what's there dynamically.

Another option is for a python script to SSH into the server, list the contents of a directory and then download. This presumes you have programmatic access to the server.

If access to the server is a no, and there is no dynamic list then the last option would be to go to this website where you know the photos are and scrape their paths and download them. However this may scrape unwanted data such as other images, icons, etc.

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-scrape-websites-with-python-and-beautifulsoup-5946935d93fe

Comment: Hi Marcus, me being lazy here: since I only want to download my photos, isn't there a way to download something like *.jpg using the wget python tool?

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly it is how do you know what are your files/urls dynamically. wget will get any URL you ask it to. So you would want to find these URLs/paths to the files and put them in an array. Then iterate though the array of images and download them. The easy part is the download code, the hard part is telling the script _what_ you want to download.